# How can insert array of multiple inputs in database?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm inserting an array of multiple inputs. but when i dd it or create it doesn't insert or returning any values. How can i use create in this situation? I'm new to laravel.

```php
foreach ($data['sku'] as $key => $val) {


    $attrCountSKU = ProductsAttribute::where('sku', $val)->count();
    if ($attrCountSKU > 0) {
        return back()->with('error', 'SKU already exists for this product! Please input another SKU.');
    }

    $attrCountSizes = ProductsAttribute::where(['product_id' => $product->id, 'size' => $data['size'][$key]])->count();

    if ($attrCountSizes > 0) {
        return back()->with('error', 'Size already exists for this product! Please input another Size.');
    }


    $attribute = new ProductsAttribute;
    $attribute->product_id = $product->id;
    $attribute->sku = $val;
    $attribute->size = $data['size'][$key];


    $attribute->price = $data['price'][$key];
    $attribute->stock = $data['stock'][$key];

    dd($attribute);
    dd($attribute->create());
}
```

Comment: Here's my validator above foreach 
$data = request()->validate([
                'sku.*' => 'required',
                'price.*' => 'required', 
                'size.*' => 'required',
                'stock.*' => 'required',
               ]);

Comment: always put your code in the question. you can use the edit link to do that.

Comment: This is outside the scope of the question, but if you are adding multiple items in a single request you should consider what might happen if one insert fails for any reason. Wrapping the inserts in a transaction, and rolling them back if any fail, may be prudent to ensure that you don't end up duplicate instances if one fails and the data is resubmitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the model, using the `save()` method.

Add this after setting all the attributes:

```php
$attribute->save();

return $attribute->id // Will be set as the object has been inserted
```

You could also use the `create()` method to create and insert the model in one go:

```php
$attribute = ProductsAttribute::create([
    'product_id' => $product->id,
    'sku' => $val,
    'size' => $data['size'][$key],
    'price' => $data['price'][$key],
    'stock' => $data['stock'][$key],
]);
```

Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Comment: are there any issues if i use create() since i've set protected fillable on my model?

Comment: You could use create, and pass an array, as long as all of them are in fillable. Will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @atymic I'll wait for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$attribute->create()` you should use `$attribute->save()` method.

Or with the `create()` method you can do like this

```
$flight = ProductsAttribute::create(
    [
        'product_id' => $product->id,
        'sku' => $val,
        'size' => $data['size'][$key],
        'price' => $data['price'][$key],
        'stock' => $data['stock'][$key],            
    ]
);
```